# How to get the output for all the values from the given time values?

Tags: python, dictionary, datetime

```
    import datetime

    data = {'13:55':0,'13:56':1,'13:57':2, '13:58':3}


    while True:
       timee = datetime.datetime.now()
       time = timee.strftime("%H:%M")
       while time not in data:
          timee = datetime.datetime.now()
          time = timee.strftime("%H:%M")
          if time in data:
             print('Done')
             print(data[time])
```

From the given code, I always get an output in case of the first or the last object in the dictionary, for example, if the current time is 13:55, I want it to display the output 'done', similarly if the time is 13:56, I want the same output and so on. Also, I don't want to break the loop since I want my program to run continuously. But it only gives me an output in case of 13:55 or 13:58 or it wouldn't even give me an output.

Whereas what I want is basically, I want it to give me an output every time the time is present in the dictionary. Please help me.

(I'm really sorry if you don't get it, I've tried my best to put this forward).

If any questions please let me know.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: why do you need the inner loop if you just want to run the code continuously? you should be able to remove it completely an just keep the `if` statement without getting a different output.

Comment: Ok, but then how will I check if the time is there in the dictionary. Like, with the while loop I'm basically updating the time. So, in the above program, for example, if we want the program to display the output at 13:55 and when the time is 13:55, we can only check it by using the if loop inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an illustration of my comment; at the moment, both your `while` loops do the same thing; you can simplify to

```
import datetime
import time

data = {'13:51':0,'13:52':1,'13:53':2, '13:54':3,
        'found':[]}

while True:
   t = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")
   if (t in data) & (t not in data['found']):
      print(f'Done, found time {t} in data\n  value: {data[t]}')
      data['found'].append(t)
   time.sleep(1)
```

I've added a little helper key to track which times were found.

Comment: Hey, yes, I did try what you had said, but if you run the program and check, the output gets printed continuously.

Comment: @IshaanDugar: ah ok, so you only want to print the value *once* if the clock reaches the according hour/minut?

Comment: Yea, I want the output for every time value in the keys, not just one and it should just print it once.

Comment: @IshaanDugar: made an edit (now also tested...). that will print the value as soon as the time is right (only once). I've also added a time.sleep for one second so the code doesn't demand too many resources.

Comment: Ah man, thank you so much. It works perfectly as expected. Thanks for giving your time to help. Much appreciated.